# How is variogramST dealing with distance and time?

Tags: r, data-visualization, gstat, covariogram

I'm new in [spatio-temporal](/questions/tagged/spatio-temporal) analysis in [r](/questions/tagged/r) so I don't know if what I'm doing is right. I have a lot of spatio-temporal data and I would like to plot a spatio-temporal sample variogram.

My problem is that I don't really understand how `variogramST` (package: gstat) works. Is `spacelag` in km or what? 
This is what I've done by now:

```
var_st <- variogramST (datast~1, data=DF, tunits="days", tlags=seq(0, 93, by= 31), 
                       boundaries=seq(0, 100, by=25), na.omit=T, assumeRegular=F)
```

**My second question is:**

Is it plotting variogram at exact distance 25, 50, 75, 100? For example, if two cities have a distance e.g 12 is `variogramST` considering it? Or is it just considering pairs of observation with exact distance 25, 50, 75, 100?
Moreover, I have monthly data. I read that in this case the best option is to choose `tunits="days"` and I choose `tlags=seq(0, 93, by= 31)`, is it right? I don't know how to deal with it otherwise.

Thank you very much for all of those people who are going to answer me!

Comment: There is no argument `tunits`; is it a copy&paste error? The argument `tunit` can be used only when `data` is a STIDF object.

Answer (score 0):

1. The spatial distance unit depends on the coordinate reference system of your input data, see sp::spDistsN1 for details.
2. The empirical variogram relies on a binning - distance classes. Observations in space and time are grouped by their approximate spatial distance (e.g. 0 km to 25 km; 25 km to 50 km, ... according to `cutoff`, `width` and `boundaries`). 
   In time, it also depends on the class of the object you provide to variogramST:

   - For a STFDF, the `tlags` are evaluated as ids of the time slot of the STFDF, in your case  observations at the same time id, with 31, 62 and 93 ids difference - most likely not what you want, assuming every id in the time slot of `DF` refers to a new month, you need to use 0:3. The argument `tunit` has no effect here.
   - If the data object is an STIDF, temporal distances are also binned to separation ranges where `tlags` are used as the breaks between classes with the temporal unit `tunit`.

See the package spacetime for details on the representation of spatio-temporal data as STFDF, STSDF, and STIDF.

HTH